# how to store public key as c array

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I've been looking for an answer for this for a while so i though i might aswell post what I've found.

I'm using openssl to sign and verify license using private key to sign and public key to verify.

since I'm sending the public key to the client for verification, I can't give it to him and ask for path to key, because he can change the public key and encrypt the message using his own private/public keys.

the solution: store the public key inside the C program as an array.

now i need to change my code of reading the public key from:

```
EVP_PKEY   *public_key = NULL;

public_key_fd = fopen( public_key_path, "r" );
if ( !public_key_fd )
     // something went wrong
PEM_read_PUBKEY( public_key_fd, &public_key, NULL, NULL );
fclose( public_key_path );
```

to something that uses a string instead of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we need to understand what does the look like, using cat:

```
cat public_key.pem
```

we get

```
---- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ----
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB/nAmOjTmezNUDKYvEeIRf2YnwM9/uUG1d0BYs
c8/tRtx+RGi7N2lUbp728MXGwdnL9od4cItzky/zVdLZE2cycOa18xBK9cOWmcKS
0A8FYBxEQWJ/q9YVUgZbFKfYGaGQxsER+A0w/fX8ALuk78ktP31K69LcQgxIsl7r
NzxsoOQKJ/CIxOGMMxczYTiEoLvQhapFQMs3FL96didKr/QbrfB1WT6s3838SEaX
fgZvLef1YB2xmfhbT9OXFE3FXvh2UPBfN+ffE7iiayQf/2XR+8j4N4bW30DiPtOQ
LGUrH1y5X/rpNZNlWW2+jGIxqZtgWg7lTy3mXy5x836Sj/6L
---- END PUBLIC KEY ----
```

I've read this char by char to understand where are the '\n' and other invisible characters and what I've found is that each line ends with '\n'

so what we get as an array for C will be:

```
char *key_string = "---- BEGIN PUBLIC KEY ----\nAAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB/nAmOjTmezNUDKYvEeIRf2YnwM9/uUG1d0BYs\nc8/tRtx+RGi7N2lUbp728MXGwdnL9od4cItzky/zVdLZE2cycOa18xBK9cOWmcKS\n0A8FYBxEQWJ/q9YVUgZbFKfYGaGQxsER+A0w/fX8ALuk78ktP31K69LcQgxIsl7r\nNzxsoOQKJ/CIxOGMMxczYTiEoLvQhapFQMs3FL96didKr/QbrfB1WT6s3838SEaX\nfgZvLef1YB2xmfhbT9OXFE3FXvh2UPBfN+ffE7iiayQf/2XR+8j4N4bW30DiPtOQ\nLGUrH1y5X/rpNZNlWW2+jGIxqZtgWg7lTy3mXy5x836Sj/6L\n---- END PUBLIC KEY ----\n";
```

and The code needed to read a key from a char array is:

```
EVP_PKEY    *public_key = NULL;
BIO         *bio;

bio = BIO_num_mem_buf( key_string, strlen( key_string ) );
PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY( bio, &public_key, NULL, NULL );
```

**explaination:** PEM_read_PrivateKey() is a wrapper around PEM_ASN1_read() (which reads an arbitrary ASN.1 object from a
PEM-encoded blob) and d2i_PrivateKey() (which knows how to read a private key blob specifically).

PEM_ASN1_read() simply creates a BIO from the FILE* that you give it, and calls PEM_ASN1_read_bio(). If
you want, you can instead create a BIO from your string using something like BIO_new_mem_buf() and call
PEM_ASN1_read_bio() yourself. (A BIO is an openssl object that's like a more general-purpose FILE*.)

BTW, if your keys are stored in a database, there's probably no need for them to be PEM-encoded; you can save a
bit of space and time by storing them in DER format and calling d2i_PrivateKey() directly. (PEM format is
more or less just base64-encoded DER.) There's a FAQ entry on this:
    http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG3